# SQL - Delete row if within time interval of previous row

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I have 27 tables of machine process data with cols: id, timestamp, col1..col70+ and up to 4 million rows.
The sample rate changed from 1 per 10 secs to 1 per 30 secs. 
How do I delete rows in each table (independently) where the timestamp of any row is within 21 seconds of the previous chronological timestamp (effectively changing the sample rate of all rows to 1/30 secs)? 
Do not assume "id" or "timestamp" is in any order, there are no foreign keys, "id" is identity and primary key column.
These are non-relational, historical data tables.
These are some rows from one table as example.
Early on the sample interval was 10 secs, now 30 secs.

```
id        Timestamp
949046  2015-03-02 02:54:49.740   --(arbitrarily starting here)
949047  2015-03-02 02:54:59.757   --delete - within 21 secs of 949046
949048  2015-03-02 02:55:09.757   --delete - within 21 secs of 949046
949049  2015-03-02 02:55:19.757   --keep - > 21 secs from 949046
949050  2015-03-02 02:55:29.727   --delete - within 21 secs of **949049**
949051  2015-03-02 02:55:39.727   --delete - within 21 secs of 949049
949052  2015-03-02 02:55:49.743   --keep - > 21 secs from 949049
949053  2015-03-02 02:55:59.727   --delete - within 21 secs of **949052**
.
.
3370919 2016-10-22 10:26:23.510   --keep assuming > 21 secs from previous row
3370920 2016-10-22 10:26:53.570   --keep - > 21 secs from 3370919
3370921 2016-10-22 10:27:23.617   --keep - > 21 secs from 3370920
```

Comment: With the data already in there, EVERY row will have a timestamp value less  than 21 secs ahead of the previous one. What you need to do is  decide which values of the second you want to keep and which ones you want to throw away. Like for each set of records with the same id and the same minute value, keep one and only row with seconds values between 0 - 29, and one and only one row with values 30 - 59.

Comment: Charles, I can't get your suggestion to run as is - the mm (month) in dateadd causes an overflow. Did you mean mi (minute) and isn't "minute" a function?

Comment: Let me throw in that what I "know" of SQL is entirely due to you folks that answer these questions. I am able to do many things, in fact everything I need (find and explain gaps and islands, insert missing data from other tables, etc., etc.. Thank you to all that answer questions here.  This is the last piece of table cleanup that is kicking my backside.

Comment: Yes, it should have been `mi`, my bad, sorry. But no I meant to use the `DateAdd()`/`DateDiff()` functions, the expressions are designed to get the exact datetime for "on the minute" and "on the half-Minute" for every minute in every date present in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as not to leave this open, this is what I came up with using TT as test table and SQL Server 2012:

```
Drop table TT
Select *, row_number() over (order by timestamp) RN
into TT 
from MyTable
```

Make col RN the Primary Key column (dropped execution time by factor of 30+)

Loop Solution:

```
declare @LowWindow datetime = (Select timestamp from TT where RN=1 ), 
    @HiWindow datetime = (dateadd(ss,21,(Select timestamp from TT where RN=1))), 
    @MaxLoop int = (select top (1) count(id) from TT),
    @LoopCount int = 1

Loop1:

if ((select timestamp from TT where RN = @LoopCount+1) > @LowWindow and (select timestamp from TT where RN = @LoopCount+1)< @HiWindow)
    Begin
        Delete from TT where rn = @LoopCount + 1
        Set @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
    End

Else 
    begin
        set @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
        set @LowWindow = (select timestamp from TT where RN = @LoopCount)
        set @HiWindow = (dateadd(ss,21, @LowWindow))
    end

if (@LoopCount > @Maxloop)
    goto EndQuery
Else 
    GOTO Loop1

EndQuery:
```

Remove PK constraint from and delete col RN from TT, replace MyTable with TT, reinstate PK constraint on col ID in MyTable.

Took 1 hour 54 minutes to execute on a table of 3,367,000 rows, 980MB.
Feel free to comment.

I'd love to see a set theory solution!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using between?

```
DECLARE @vdate VARCHAR(24);

SELECT @vdate=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TimeStamp,103)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),TimeStamp,108)+':30';

DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN @TimeStampCurrent AND @vdate
```

Comment: Christian, what do I set @TimeStampCurrent to and is Select missing From?

Comment: @TimeStampCurrent would be the min(TimeStamp).

Comment: Select @TimeStampCurrent = timestamp FROM table WHERE (your conditions);

Comment: In any solution I could come up with, the Where clause always included a windowed function, but thank you for the input.